# Отлов изменение базы MySQL с помощью GoLang

Tags: mysql, golang

?Как можно "красиво" понять что в таблице базы данных MySQL произошли изменения при помощи GoLang, при этом не выкачивая всю таблицу по таймеру

Одно из решений, приходящих на ум, использовать триггеры в базе данных, но не знаю как с ними взаимодействовать через GoLang

Comment: Да, можно на таблицу "навесить" набор триггеров (AFTER INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE), которые по факту своего срабатывания будут в некую служебную таблицу записывать текущий штамп времени. Тогда запросом можно получить этот штамп времени последнего изменения, и сравнить с временем предыдущего обращения, хранимым на уровне клиента. Неравенство означает, что изменения были. Однако всё равно это поллинг - для обнаружения факта изменения клиент должен с требуемой периодичностью перезапрашивать данные с сервера.

Comment: Окей, понял) спасибо